# Coupling suggestions required

Tags: mechanical, machine-design, coupling

I am looking for a **Hub-Shaft** coupling which has **no** alignment error (angular as well as parallel) and can be used for a fixed axial distance. No misalignments can be ensured by [PL032X050M](https://tt-net.tsubakimoto.co.jp/tecs/pdct/kpl/pdct_Dtl_PL-ML.asp?kata=PL032X050M) but in order to tighten it, it needs to be screwed and the distance between the shaft and hub changes. Kindly suggest a suitable coupling for this purpose.

Comment: Sliding joint. There are many: toothed shafts, square shafts,lemon shafts. A search will give you lots.